# Unresolved Host Exception Android

Tags: java, android, rest

I'm trying to call a RESTful web service from an Android application using the following method:

```
HttpHost target = new HttpHost("http://" + ServiceWrapper.SERVER_HOST,ServiceWrapper.SERVER_PORT);
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("/list");
String result = null;
HttpEntity entity = null;
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(target, get);
    entity = response.getEntity();
    result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (entity!=null)
        try {
            entity.consumeContent();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
}
return result;
```

I can browse to address and see the xml results using the Android Emulator browser and from my machine. I have given my app the INTERNET permission.

I'm developing with eclipse.

I've seen it mentioned that I might need to configure a proxy but since the web service I'm calling is on port 80 this shouldn't matter should it? I can call the method with the browser.

Any ideas?

Comment: Proxy settings won't matter unless your device is behind a proxy server.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I still can't get this working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the problem might be on the first line:

```
new HttpHost("http://" + ServiceWrapper.SERVER_HOST,ServiceWrapper.SERVER_PORT);
```

The `HttpHost` constructor expects a hostname as its first argument, not a hostname with a `"http://"` prefix.

Try removing `"http://"` and it should work:

```
new HttpHost(ServiceWrapper.SERVER_HOST,ServiceWrapper.SERVER_PORT);
```

Answer (score 3):

The error means the URL can't be resolved via DNS. The are a many problems which might cause this. If you sit behind a proxy you should configure it to be used.

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(”proxy”,port,”protocol”);
client.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

Also check that your internetpermission looks like this

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.INTERNET”></uses-permission>
```

As sometimes it won't work as empty tag.

Also check out [Emulator Networking](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) and the limitations section there

Comment: I'm not sure about the proxy settings as I'm only hitting port 80 and the emulator's browser can call the webservice.

Comment: This did it for me, when using a normal HttpGet("http: //host/path");  - Eclipse doesn't seem to put this XML tag in.  Thank you!

Comment: <uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.INTERNET”></uses-permission> worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I would double check that the network permission is set correctly. Try something basic like

```
String address -"http://www.google.com";
URL url = new URL(address);             
InputStream in = url.openStream();
```

to verify that you have your permissions set up right.

After that use your favorite protocol analyzer(I am a wireshark fan) to figure if you are sending out the right packets. I believe that you need to pass in the complete URL to HTTPGet but I am only about 80% sure.

Comment: Right, I can get data back using this method. However I can't figure out why the original code doesn't work. I'm not seeing anything in Fiddler for either!

Comment: Is this method a valid way to call a REST web service? I.e. consuming the input stream into a string?

Comment: It is a very simple method but it might be adequate depending on what you are doing.  I am not familiar with fiddler but I am not sure if it is the same as a packet sniffer.
 I am guessing the URL or host is wrong. I would try passing in the full URL ("http://" + ServiceWrapper.SERVER_HOST+"//list") and see if that helps.

Comment: Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy (i.e. a HTTP proxy server used to analyze HTTP traffic) and therefore not a packet sniffer.

Answer (score 0):

Change first line in your code:

```
HttpHost(ServiceWrapper.SERVER_HOST,ServiceWrapper.SERVER_PORT);
```