# Web Service use in Android

Tags: android, web-services

How can we use Web services in Android Applications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See my question here: [Unresolved Host Exception Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992880/unresolved-host-exception-android)

Comment: Thank you very much i think it is very useful for me. anther question is can we use SOAP in ANDROID?

Comment: Since SOAP is an Xml format you can use the SAXParser built in to the Android framework to parse it. I'm not sure if Android has a "service reference" model ala .NET/Netbeans Java