# How to use webservices in android?

Tags: android, web-services

I want to know about how to call webservices in android I had done a lot of search from Internet and  have read several tutorials but was not  able to understand much and manipulate, can anyone suggest any Tutorial, or provide any Pdf file or any  book related to web services so that I can understand it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Service use in Android.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097440/web-service-use-in-android)

Comment: I haven't worked on web services but these are some useful tutorial might help u http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/03/03/how-to-consume-web-services-from-android-applications-using-ksoap2/ http://romenlaw.blogspot.com/2008/08/consuming-web-services-from-android.html http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/ http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-xml-binding-simple-tutorial.html http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-parsing-web-service-response-part-1/

Answer (score 3):

The first reading I would suggest is [this one](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_intro.asp) - this is the W3School tutorial. Don't forget to read the related chapters included in this tutorial - Soap, Wsdl, etc - as this tutorial taken as a standalone would not be so valuable. This tutorial is not specifically related to Android but will give you all the information needed to understand the use and constraints of this kind of architecture, and then structure your project.

Under Android, you will face the specific contraint of mobile phones and tablets: the network can be down, and is often down: in the tube, in a basement, in any area that have a bad network coverage. So you will have to take care of this, either by caching data or allowing the application to work in degraded mode when no network is available. These are just examples as I don't know your context.

After that, Android is developed in Java, with a specific API that comes on top of the regular `java.*` packages. These are just tools to implement the client side. On server side, depending of whether you control these services, you may also have some implementation to do. If so, this can be Java, PHP, .Net, anything: one of the purpose of the web services architecture is to stay independant of the remote implementation to only care the exchange protocol. But reading your question, I think the two first points are more important (or have an higher priority let's say) than the implementation as they are prerequisites. (**EDIT**: Anyway, a useful discussion about that can be found [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android).)

Comment: i have already read this but later on i want to call webservise in my project therfore i want to do a small experiment with that so suggst any useful tutorial for this

Comment: Ok! In that case, I suggest reading this discussion on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android

Answer (score 2):

Android Doesn't have it's own tool then you should use your own or use some Thing Like KSOAP2.

You Can Use This.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap