# How to Connect a Webservice to an Android Application

Tags: java, android, rest

I am new to web services and I want to make a RESTful web service, and connect it to an Android application.  I would like the steps or a tutorial on how to do this.

I started to create my service using this link [This link gives steps to create web service but I can't get why it is using entity classes (customer , DicountCode) from an existing database. What are these classes for?](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are new to this zone, make sure you check out previous answers to similar questions. However you can find a tutorial to access webservices from android [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr) and a question similar to yours was answered on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827881/how-to-use-webservices-in-android).

Answer (score 4):

you can try it to connect and parse automatically your web service
http://www.wsdl2code.com

```
SampleService srv1 = new SampleService();
     req = new Request();                     
     req.companyId = "1";
     req.userName = "userName";                                     
     req.password = "pas";
     Response response =    srv1.ServiceSample(req);
```