# Android connect to MS SQL server

Tags: android

What is the best way for get data form MS SQL server remote for Android application?
Use JDBC ? or create something like API REST? or something else?
How did succided or had other resolf this problem?

Comment: anyway, I can help you with webservice. Contact me:
iterbi7@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose a WebService and connect to it with Android. You need to do query or everything else directly from your webservice and not from android. Check out these links:

- [How to Connect a Webservice to an Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222977/how-to-connect-a-webservice-to-an-android-application)
- [How to connect Android app to MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732853/how-to-connect-android-app-to-mysql-database)
- http://m-zeeshanarif.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-connecting-to-server-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

Do not directly connect to the database. The reason is quite simple: Anyone can get access to your database when decompiling your app. Once done this person can execute CRUD-operations on your database.

The best way is to write/have a server which accepts and handles commands send from your app.

Comment: It's good reason :) thx